# PHP, Get tomorrows date from date

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

I have a PHP date in the form of `2013-01-22` and I want to get tomorrows date in the same format, so for example `2013-01-23`.

How is this possible with PHP?

Answer (score 233, accepted):

Use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)

```
$datetime = new DateTime('tomorrow');
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Or:

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2013-01-22');
$datetime->modify('+1 day');
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Or:

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2013-01-22');
$datetime->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Or in PHP 5.4+:

```
echo (new DateTime('2013-01-22'))->add(new DateInterval("P1D"))
                                 ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: This uses current, I need to pass in a given date.

Answer (score 109):

```
 $tomorrow = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('tomorrow'));
```

or

```
  $tomorrow = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day"));
```

Help Link: [STRTOTIME()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime)

Comment: I used this one and of all answers is the shortest and simplest version, thanks !

Comment: This is cool and will also give you yesterday: `-1 day`

Answer (score 17):

Since you tagged this with [strtotime](/questions/tagged/strtotime), you can use it with the `+1 day` modifier like so:

```
$tomorrow_timestamp = strtotime('+1 day', strtotime('2013-01-22'));
```

That said, it's a much better solution to [use DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14460546/698179).

Answer (score 14):

```
<? php 

//1 Day = 24*60*60 = 86400

echo date("d-m-Y", time()+86400); 

?>
```

Comment: Note that this will fail in edge cases (daylight savings time).

Comment: This answer is wrong. I have a cronjob use this in a loop, and the system got died.

Answer (score 8):

`echo date ('Y-m-d',strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($your_date)));`

Answer (score 5):

Use `DateTime`:

To get tomorrow from now :

```
$d = new DateTime('+1day');
$tomorrow = $d->format('d/m/Y h.i.s');
echo $tomorrow;
```

> Results : 28/06/2017 08.13.20

To get tomorrow from a date :

```
$d = new DateTime('2017/06/10 08.16.35 +1day')
$tomorrow = $d->format('d/m/Y h.i.s');
echo $tomorrow;
```

> Results : 11/06/2017 08.16.35

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * get tomorrow's date in the format requested, default to Y-m-d for MySQL (e.g. 2013-01-04)
 *
 * @param string
 *
 * @return string
 */
public static function getTomorrowsDate($format = 'Y-m-d')
{
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('tomorrow'));

    return $date->format($format);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By strange it can seem it works perfectly fine: `date_create( '2016-02-01 + 1 day' );`

`echo date_create( $your_date . ' + 1 day' )->format( 'Y-m-d' );`

Should do it

Answer (score -1):

here's working function

```
function plus_one_day($date){
 $date2 = formatDate4db($date);
 $date1 = str_replace('-', '/', $date2);
 $tomorrow = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date1 . "+1 days"));
 return $tomorrow; }
```

Comment: what does the formatDate4db function do? Why replace the dashes with slashes in the string?

Comment: formatDate4db function pass the date and it make a format like database mysql format , and str_replace function , i have date format 2019/12/10 and replace with -

Answer (score -4):

```
$date = '2013-01-22';
$time = strtotime($date) + 86400;
echo date('Y-m-d', $time);
```

Where 86400 is the # of seconds in a day.

Comment: No, one day doesn't always have 86400 seconds.

Comment: I don't get the problem.
Please explain @nickb

Comment: @Aiyion.Prime days that make the switch to or from daylight saving time do not have 86400 seconds

Comment: I thought of that, DST is initiated at two o'clock and should therefore never result in a different date?

Comment: The problem isn't daylight savings. Times in a database really should be stored as UTC which has no daylight saving time. If you're storing your dates in UTC this will work fine but is a bit obtuse.