# Add one day to get_the_date in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

In the WPTouch theme, the posting date is displayed in a large bubble. However, posts are added the night before, so the day is behind by one. To fix this, I changed this line:

```
<?php wptouch_the_time( 'j' ); ?>
```

to this:

```
    <?php
            $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', mysql2date('m-d-Y', $post->post_date));
            $date->modify('+1 day');
            echo $date->format('j');
    ?>
```

This works, but is crazy ugly. I think there should be a better way to get from mysql date to php DateTime.

Comment: I'd rather use the correct date in WordPress (by scheduling the post for the next day instead of publishing it directly)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460518/php-get-tomorrows-date-from-date

Comment: Well, the less correct version would be to use `date` and `strtotime`: `echo date('j', strtotime($post->post_date . ' +1 day'));`

Answer (score 6):

You can use this [filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) to modify the date before it is given to the theme with the function `get_the_date()` (which `wptouch_the_time()` most probably uses to get the date):

```
add_filter( 'get_the_date', 'modify_get_the_date', 10, 3 );
function modify_get_the_date( $value, $format, $post ) {
    $date = new DateTime( $post->post_date );
    $date->modify( "+1 day" );
    if ( $format == "" )
        $format = get_option( "date_format" );
    return( $date->format( $format ) );
}
```

That being said, instead of modifying the date when it is read from the database, it would be better to just store the publication date when it is written. You can do this by scheduling posts for the next day, instead of publishing them directly.

Comment: For more than 1 day to add how it should be

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
<?php
$date=date_create();
date_modify($date,"+1 month");
echo date_format($date,"Y-m-d");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way i always do this is using the [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) method

```php
<?php 
$format = ""; // your date format
$oneDayLater = strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($columnValue));
$out = date($format, $oneDayLater);
?>
```