# PHP Date "l" +1 day

Tags: php, date, datetime, dayofweek, weekday

Thanks for the help, but I have found my answer here: [PHP, Get tomorrows date from date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460518/php-get-tomorrows-date-from-date)

My question is probably pretty simple, but I can't find an answer anywhere for it. I am looking to print if something is open or not. As you can see here in the code, it is a working chekcer, but it's checking today, and not tomorrow. What do I need to do, to make it check the next day instead of today?

Thanks

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Oslo');
$dag = date("l");
$uke = date("W");
$åpent = "Nei";
if ($dag == "Monday") {
    $åpent = "Nei";
} else if ($dag == "Wednesday") {
    $åpent = "Ja! (17-22)";
} else if ($dag == "Thursday") {
    $åpent = "Ja! (17-22)";
} else if ($dag == "Friday") {
    $åpent = "Ja! (18-00:30)";
} else if ($dag == "Saturday") {
    $åpent = "Nei";
} else if ($dag == "Sunday") {
    $åpent = "Nei";
}
if ($uke % 2 == 0) {
    $åpent = "Ja! (17-21)";
} else {
    $åpent = "Nei";
}
echo $åpent;
?>
```

The question that was commented does not do what I need. I am looking for a way for PHP to print the next day in `date("l")` form.

Comment: @Alexis I saw this post, but it didn't meet my requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace line 3 and 4 with these:

```
$t = strtotime('+1 day', time());
$dag = date("l", $t);
$uke = date("W", $t);
```

Basically you are getting the next day from the time your script is executing. Then use that time in the second argument of `date()` function (by default it considers the value returned by `time()`. You can specify your own value).

I can say a lot about `strtotime`. Everything you need to know it's in the official documentation here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php