# Create DateTime for JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json, laravel-5.6

I need to hit an API in PHP Laravel and passing Raw body date in it. It requires DataTime to be sent as required by json show in below format.

```
"ShippingDateTime": "\/Date(1484085970000-0500)\/",
```

How can I create date like this in PHP/Laravel where I can get any future date (current date + 1). Currently it's giving error that:

```
DateTime content '23-01-2021' does not start with '\/Date(' and end with ')\/' as required for JSON.
```

Comment: Well thats not a standard date format so you will have to do some manual fiddling to make it look like that

Comment: What format is that?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I'm also not able to found what format is that and how can I make it in PHP. But in there example documentation they showed \/Date(1484085970000-0500)\/ but as it's a past date so it also give error that date should be of future.

Comment: Let this be a lesson to everyone that inventing your own date interchange format is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a Unix timestamp with milliseconds (the `000`) on the end, plus a timezone identifier. You should be able to construct that with the [date formatting flags `UvO` (unix time, milliseconds, timezone)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

(These are in my timezone, `-06:00`)

```
echo date('UvO');
// 1611339488000-0600

// Surround it with the /Date()/ it requests
// Encode it as JSON wherever is appropriate in your code
echo json_encode('/Date(' . date('UvO') . ')/');
// "\/Date(1611339460000-0600)\/"
```

Assuming you have your dates in `DateTime` objects, call their `format()` method to produce your desired date format.

```
// create your DateTime as appropriate in your application
$yourdate = new \DateTime();

echo json_encode('/Date(' . $yourdate->format('UvO') . ')/');

// Set it ahead 1 day in the future
$yourdate->modify('+1 day');
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked well, but can you help me how I can use this to get next date? Like currently it give current date but I wanted to make two dates like this, current date + 1. current date + 2.

Comment: By `current_date`, do you mean _today_'s date, or current relative to that past date you had in your example? Calling a `DateTime` object's `modify()` method can change it ahead 1 or 2 days: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460518/php-get-tomorrows-date-from-date/14460546

Comment: I mean today's date by it. I'll try your update answer, Thank you :)